# How to run an infinite loop in the background

Tags: bash

How can I run an infinite loop in the background, while continuing on with the script's execution?

Example "script":

```
while true; do something_in_the_background; done

do_something_while_the_loop_goes_on_in_the_background

for 1 2 3; do somethingelse; done

exit 0
```

---

This (notice the `&`) seems to crash the whole system after a short while:

```
while true; do
  something_in_the_background &
done

do_something_while_the_loop_goes_on_in_the_background

for 1 2 3; do somethingelse; done

exit 0
```

Comment: Not suprised you are creating lots of processes.

Comment: Asking directions for a fork bomb?

Comment: Could you please tell the intention behind running an infinite loop in the background ?

Comment: One example of checking or monitor file changes using infinite loop (ignore the inotify thing). @neuron

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With the `&` inside the loop it will start a new process in the background and as fast as it can do it again without waiting for the first process to end.  Instead I think you want to put the loop into the background, so put the `&` on the loop itself like

```
while /bin/true; do
    something_in_the_background
done &

# more stuff
```

Comment: Is there any way to end this loop? Trying to kill the underlying process with its PID doesn't work.

Comment: The `&` will put the loop into the background.  If you're doing this from an interactive shell, or one with job control enabled, you can do `fg` to bring background jobs to the fore.  This loop will not have its own PID though, it will be just one of the things that the parent is doing.  Killing the script should also terminate the loop if you're doing it that way.  Alternately, you could change the `while` condition to test for, say, the existence of file and have it exit when the file no longer exists

Comment: This solution is not good. When you have script that prints something inside that loop example `echo "test" | tee -a $REPORT_FILE` , then the whole terminal will have this output. How do you prevent this ?

Comment: @MaXi32. `tee` will write to the terminal, so if you're ruining a command like that it will indeed run a lot of them at once and fill the screen

Comment: @EricRenouf I solved it by running the script with `nohup` and still use tee. So, it won't print in the terminal. Thanks for pointing that out and your solution works great. TQ.

Comment: @MaXi32. if you don't want it to print to the screen why are you using `tee` instead of just redirecting?

Comment: @EricRenouf because my loop has some weird conditionals that it needs tee inside to display the output when running it manually from the terminal. In brief, I made 2 options to the script which can run manually or in background.

Comment: @RafaelCamposNunes Since the script is running and executing part of the while loop, you can end the script by creating a file FLAG and stop the script by checking the flag. Example `echo "stop" > FLAG`; `flag=$(head -1 ${FLAG})`; Then in your while loop: `while /bin/true; do if [ "${flag}" == "stop" ]; then exit 1 `echo "run" > FLAG`, something_in_the_background done & `

Answer (score 15):

```
while : ; do something ; done &
```

- Earlier Bourne shells didn't have `true` and `false` as built-in commands. `true` was instead simply aliased to `:`, and `false` to something like `let 0`.
- `&` at the end of the line backgrounds the process
- `:` is the null command, as described by "help :": `No effect; the command does nothing. Exit Status: Always succeeds.`

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved by explaining it—the OP may not know what `:` means and probably doesn't know why you've moved the `&` to the end. Also, changing the spacing to make it a one-liner is just confusing—it's a change which is very visible but is entirely unimportant.

Comment: Edited the post as per your reviews

Answer (score 0):

Putting sleep of say .1 or .01 seconds would make your loop more CPU friendly. But as pointed out be Eric Renouf, the & should be at the end of the loop, not inside it.