# Testing an infinite loop in the background within Docker?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, background-process

I want to run a background queue working in my docker image:

```
php artisan queue:work --daemon --sleep=1 --tries=3 &
```

Immediately after that it starts Apache `httpd` running a PHP `laravel` app. The `laravel` app sends push notifications out to Redis. The background queue worker collects the messages from Redis and sends them via a push service.

That works and logs out every second. In case the background command crashes I would like it to restart. According to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223780/72040 I can run a command infinitely in the background with something like:

```
while true; do php $QUEUE_WORK; done &
```

To test this I ran my container with `docker run` then did `docker exec -it` to login and see:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
100000       1     0  0 19:55 ?        00:00:00 httpd -D FOREGROUND
100000      21     1  0 19:55 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -e /tmp/scripts/run
100000      22    21  1 19:55 ?        00:00:01 php artisan queue:work --sleep=1 --tries=3
100000      43     1  0 19:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/cat
100000      50     1  0 19:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/cat
100000      51     1  0 19:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/cat
100000      52     1  0 19:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/cat
100000      53     1  0 19:55 ?        00:00:00 httpd -D FOREGROUND
...
100000     130     0  1 19:57 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
100000     144   130  0 19:57 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -efww
```

I then run `kill 22` see output on the `docker run` of:

```
/tmp/scripts/run: line 10:    22 Killed                  php $QUEUE_WORK
```

The loop doesn't keep the process up. I have double checked that the loop is the code being run in the image. If I have the loop run a ”echo x: sleep 1” it runs okay.

Why doesn't the loop replace the command when I kill it?

**NOTE:** The application is deployed as multiple pods on Kubernetes with monitoring and automated restarts if the `httpd` health check URL returns an error or time-out.

I don't want to deploy the queue workers as a separate pod or as a sidecar container I want to run it as a background process in the `httpd` container so that it shares the application code with `httpd` with zero config.

I am not interested in running process monitors or other tools or technology to ”keep alive”.

My question is why does the Bash loop exit on `kill` of the process it is running?

Comment: re: `why didn't the while catch it?` the while loop itself does not put the php command in a subshell, so the pid for the php command is effectively the pid for the while command as well.  You could address this by forcing the php command into a subshell with `while true; do (php  args ...); done`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Setup

I set up the following `Dockerfile`:

```
$ more Dockerfile
From centos
ADD run.sh /tmp/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/run.sh"]
```

Setup a script, `run.sh`:

```
$ cat run.sh
while true; do sleep 15 ; echo "background"; done &

while true; do sleep 12 ; echo "foreground"; done
```

Built it:

```
$ docker build -t sleeper .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 7.791 MB
Step 1/4 : FROM centos
 ---> 49f7960eb7e4
Step 2/4 : ADD run.sh /tmp/run.sh
 ---> b4099de53780
Removing intermediate container 1ce8e3a1dac5
Step 3/4 : RUN chmod +x /tmp/run.sh
 ---> Running in e410429a6cba

 ---> 06789467e636
Removing intermediate container e410429a6cba
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT /tmp/run.sh
 ---> Running in ad8b847b505f
 ---> a2415df63f99
Removing intermediate container ad8b847b505f
Successfully built a2415df63f99
```

#### Example

Then started it up:

```
$ docker run -dit sleeper
28c19c338e6e6177529cf989f42c7f14b17f1c705a61f5244d5350f0ab8f8364
```

Then it runs repeatedly showing:

```
foreground 
background 
foreground 
background
```

Now when I watch it I can see that it's staying up, in spite of the `sleep` commands eventually "dying":

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
28c19c338e6e        sleeper             "/tmp/run.sh"       About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       focused_lumiere
```

From above we can see that this container has been up in excess of 1 minute. Here's what the `ps auxf` looks like of the inside of the container:

```
$ ps auxf
...
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root        24  0.0  0.1  11828  2964 pts/1    Ss   16:00   0:00 /bin/bash
root        58  0.0  0.1  51712  3432 pts/1    R+   16:01   0:00  \_ ps auxf
root         1  0.0  0.1  11692  2572 pts/0    Ss+  15:58   0:00 /bin/bash /tmp/
root         5  0.0  0.1  11696  2272 pts/0    S+   15:58   0:00 /bin/bash /tmp/
root        56  0.0  0.0   4368   636 pts/0    S+   16:01   0:00  \_ sleep 15
root        57  0.0  0.0   4368   664 pts/0    S+   16:01   0:00 sleep 12
```

Now if we kill the background `sleep 15` like so:

```
$ kill 56
```

And run another `docker ps`:

```
$ docker ps
...
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root        24  0.0  0.1  11828  2964 pts/1    Ss   16:00   0:00 /bin/bash
root        60  0.0  0.1  51712  3344 pts/1    R+   16:01   0:00  \_ ps auxf
root         1  0.0  0.1  11692  2572 pts/0    Ss+  15:58   0:00 /bin/bash /tmp/
root         5  0.0  0.1  11696  2272 pts/0    S+   15:58   0:00 /bin/bash /tmp/
root        59  0.0  0.0   4368   636 pts/0    S+   16:01   0:00  \_ sleep 15
root        57  0.0  0.0   4368   664 pts/0    S+   16:01   0:00 sleep 12
```

We can see that the while loop that's guarding our background `sleep 15` process has done its job and restarted another `sleep 15`.

Comment: i have accepted your answer as it shows my code will work in prod if the queue worker decides to die a natural death, i don't now why the php behaves differently. yet i have run out of curiosity for the time being. thanks.